# Undefined method `location' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I get the error when I try to access the location attribute of the profile model.
It occurs in the following line of code which is to display a link that filters search results:

```
<%= link_to_unless_current Profile.find_by_location(facet['term']).location, params.merge(location: facet['term']) %>
```

If I change:

```
Profile.find_by_location(facet['term']).location
```

to:

```
Profile.find_by_location(facet['term'])
```

the error disappears and the link shows and filters the search results correctly but has the form:

Link:`/users?location=canada` instead of just Link:`canada`

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: In your db (profiles table) you don't have any profile with location=canada (that's the nil issue).

Comment: For the link issue, do you have any route path that use the location in it?

Comment: the profile does have a canada location. I have not setup any routes for since the link just filters the search results on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is raised because, probably, there are cases where the query

```
Profile.find_by_location(facet['term'])
```

returns no results (nil) and you can't call the method `location` on a nil instance.

If you are not expecting the query to return a nil result, then check your database integrity. If you expect it, then deal with that.

One possibility is to use try as a shortcut.

```
Profile.find_by_location(facet['term']).try(:location)
```

But it can quickly become a bad habit, so don't do that unless you know what you are doing. Yo u should deal with the user input.